# Subtract Row Count in View A from Row Count in View B (Drupal)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view

I've two Views using Table Summarize to count their rows. One view is student arrivals and the other is studen departures.

I want to subtract the row count in ViewB (departures) from ViewA (arrivals) and combine them into a net figure. Perhaps combine in another view.

I am aware of union as a tool for merging but I don't want to combine the result set, I only want to subtract the row counts.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: where is the code? What have your tried doing?

Comment: Code is just two Views. I'm just using a totally basic setup with one field pulling in Users and counting them using Views Table Summarize module. You can see View A here http://class.ulearn.ie/counta and View B here http://class.ulearn.ie/countb. Its a very simple example so I can focus on the functionality I want - subtracting the row count in View B from the row count in View A.